# Не получается подключится к phpmyadmin

Tags: php, debian, mysqli, phpmyadmin, apache2

phpmyadmin лежит в директории с сайтом, стоит 2 апач и 7 пхп, на php5.6 таким образом работал, после установки php7.0.20 выдает

> The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.

Но mysqli установлен, все конфиги вроде прописаны правильно.
Есть идеи?
P.S. На серваке стоит debian jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно в конфигурации php не указана или закомментирована строка с указанием самого расширения:

```
extension=mysqli.so
```

Проверьте, что данная строка есть в действующем файле **php.ini** и не содержит символа **;** в начале.

Comment: Включена, не содержит ;

Comment: @Kirill , правильно понимаю, что через `phpinfo()` Вы проверили, что **php.ini** корректный и апач перезагружен?

Comment: Да, через phpinfo проверял, апач после установки пхп перезагружал, попробую сейчас ещё раз перезагрузить, может поможет =)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, решилось))

Comment: @Klimenkomud рад был помочь :)